# How do I loop through each row correctly?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When trying to loop through the rows...If a cell is checked, send email...
If only one row is checked, this works, but If I have multiple rows checked, to send emails- then the email sends, but the Variable 'Name', 'Gradex', and 'Date' all stays stuck on the first checked row?

```
function SendEmail_InitialConfirmation() 

{

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1x');
var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2x');

var subject = sheet2.getRange(5,1).getValue();
var message = sheet2.getRange(5,2).getValue();

var n=sheet1.getLastRow();

//Start Loop on Row 3
for (var i = 3; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {



var Name=sheet1.getRange(i,4).getValue();

var EmailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i,5).getValue();

var Gradex =sheet1.getRange(i,12).getValue();

var Date =sheet1.getRange(i,13).getDisplayValue()

var valueToCheck = sheet1.getRange(i,16).getValue();

if(valueToCheck === true)

{

message=message.replace("<Name>",Name).replace("<Gradex>",Gradex).replace("<Date>",Date);

MailApp.sendEmail(EmailAddress, subject, message,{
       
      bcc:"xxx@gmail.com",
      bcc:"xxxxxx@gmail.com",
       name:"Test Email Name"});


//Remove Checkbox from Send email column after use
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i, 16).removeCheckboxes();

//Clear 'Send' Checkbox and Check box for Email confirmation Sent
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i, 16).clearContent();
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i, 17).setValue('true');
}
}
}
```

Im confused how my loop is incorrect? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With in your loop you have overwritten message `<Name>` with `Name`, etc.  So the next pass in the loop `<Name>` no longer occurs in the message string.

**Replace**

```
message=message.replace("<Name>",Name).replace("<Gradex>",Gradex).replace("<Date>",Date);

MailApp.sendEmail(EmailAddress, subject, message,{
```

**With**

```
let message2=message.replace("<Name>",Name).replace("<Gradex>",Gradex).replace("<Date>",Date);

MailApp.sendEmail(EmailAddress, subject, message2,{
```

Comment: Thank you so Much Ed!  This problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

**Untested**

It's kind of unclear specificity wise, but it should get you in the right direction.
It's better to use `getRange()` covering multiple rows and columns and `setValues()` to place the data back whenever possible, as it'll be faster and cheaper. Thus, you'll be working with 2D arrays and their indexes begin at 0 for columns and rows.

```
function SendEmail_InitialConfirmation() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1x');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2x');
  var subject = sheet2.getRange(5, 1).getValue();
  var message = sheet2.getRange(5, 2).getValue();
  var n = sheet1.getLastRow();

  //Get the data at once
  var sheet1Data = sheet1.getRange(3, 1, sheet1.getLastRow() - 2, sheet1.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();

  for (let i = 0; i > sheet1Data.length; i++) {
    let Name = sheet1Data[i][3];
    let EmailAddress = sheet1Data[i][4];
    let Date = sheet1Data[i][11];
    let valueToCheck = sheet1Data[i][15];
    let msgSent = sheet1Data[i][16];
    if (valueToCheck === true && msgSent !== true) {
      let row = i + 4; //When working with arrays, the index starts at 0, so since the sheet data start with row 3, now you have the correct row to get its check box unchecked.
      message = message.replace("<Name>", Name).replace("<Gradex>", Gradex).replace("<Date>", Date);
      MailApp.sendEmail(EmailAddress, subject, message, {
        bcc: "xxx@gmail.com",
        bcc: "xxxxxx@gmail.com",
        name: "Test Email Name"
      });
      sheet1.getRange(row, 16).removeCheckboxes();
      sheet1.getRange(row, 17).setValue(true); //If there is another checkbox, than that should have been checked above, which I've done.
    }
  }
}
```